# Construct a set that is not closed but contains all limit points of sequences in it

Tags: general-topology

Find a Hausdorff ($T_2)$ space $(X,\tau)$ and it's subset $A$ such that

$1\cdot$ $A$ is not closed

$2\cdot$ All sequences $(x_n)\subset A$ that converge, do so to a point in $A$.

I know that for both of these conditions to be satisfied it is at least necessary for $X$ to not be a metric space and for $A$ to not be compact.

I've experimented with Sorgenfrey's space (where $[a,b)$ is open) and it's variations (like making the base $B = \{[p,q)\in\Bbb{R} | p,q\in\Bbb{Q}\}$) but couldn't get it to work.

$X=\Bbb{R}^2$ with $\tau = \{U\subset\Bbb{R}^2|\space\space |\Bbb{R}^2\setminus U|<\Bbb{N}|\}$ and $A=\{0\}\times\Bbb{R}$ seemed promising but after an hour I noticed $X$'s not even Hausdorff.

I'm really dry on ideas now, would appreciate any hints :)

Comment: Perhaps this query of not 1st countable yet t2 spaces can help: https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces?q=%20t_2%20%2B%20~First%20Countable

Comment: Thanks Peter! It just so happened that the very first result on the list (Fortissimo space with A=[0,+oo] ) satisfies all needed conditions :)

Comment: Another example would be the closed long line (the long line with the first uncountable ordinal included)